# Unable to decode json created by json.dump

Tags: python, json

I have the following code:

```
import json

idref = "../Data/Resources/oids.json"

with open(idref,"w+") as file_ref:
    try:
        ref = json.load(file_ref)
    except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError as e:
        print("decode error: {}".format(e))
        ref = {"ids":[]}

    print(ref)
    for i in range(1600,1605,1):
        ref["ids"].append(i)
    json.dump(ref,file_ref,indent=4)
```

When I run it the first time (and the oids.json file doesn't exist) I, understandably, get: `decode error: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`. I inspect the newly created file and find, as I expect:

```
{
    "ids": [
        1600,
        1601,
        1602,
        1603,
        1604
    ]
}
```

What I'm not understanding is that, when I run it again, I get exactly the same output:

```
decode error: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
{'ids': []}
```

Which is to say that I can't read the file, even though it's been created by the interpreter during the previous iteration. I've been developing in python for a while now and feel like I'm going mad... Am I missing something?

I'm running python 3.9.6 on Mac OS Montery 12.4

Comment: Opening the file in `w+` mode destroys the existing contents, so you're starting with a blank file every time.

Comment: Beside the point, but you can simplify that loop: `ref["ids"].extend(range(1600, 1605))`

Comment: Great write up at this question on the different file open modes: [Difference between modes a, a+, w, w+, and r+ in built-in open function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466000/difference-between-modes-a-a-w-w-and-r-in-built-in-open-function)

Comment: Thanks, yes I get this now, was mislead by a couple of articles I read which said that w+ starts at the beginning of the file and allows reading and writing, without making it clear that there will be nothing to read! Thanks. Happy to accept an answer from one of these comments.